# Peskin&Schroeder (4.76) - Evaluation of non-trivial part of amplitudes and Unitarity of S-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

(1)
On Peskin&Schroeder's book (P&S), page 105, it is written that

> Assuming that we are not interested in the trivial case of forward scattering where no interaction take place, we can drop the $\mathbf{1}$ in Eq.(4.72)

, hence they evaluate the amplitude with only non-trivial part, T-matrix, of S-matrix:
\begin{align}
\|\langle \{\mathbf{p}_f \}|S|\{\mathbf{k}_i\} \rangle\|^2 =\|\langle \{\mathbf{p}_f \}|iT|\{\mathbf{k}_i\} \rangle\|^2
\end{align}
where $S=1+iT$ (this def. is (4.72)).

However, I think the exact form of non-trivial part of that amplitude is then
\begin{align}
\|\langle \{\mathbf{p}_f \}|S|\{\mathbf{k}_i\} \rangle\|^2- \|\langle \{\mathbf{p}_f \}|\mathbf{1}|\{\mathbf{k}_i\} \rangle\|^2 \neq \|\langle \{\mathbf{p}_f \}|iT|\{\mathbf{k}_i\} \rangle\|^2.
\end{align}
So what did happen to its cross-term?

I think they assumed that the final states have the different number of particles or particles whose masses are different from the initial state particles.

Am I wrong?

(2) (**→ Solved.**)

I can't understand how can $S$ be unitary. From its definition with $T$, if $S$ is unitary, $T$ must satisfy

\begin{align}
SS^\dagger = (1+iT)(1-iT^\dagger) = 1 + i (T-T^\dagger) + TT^\dagger = 1. 
\end{align}

If $T$ satisfies $T^\dagger=T$ and $T^2 = 1$, then it is OK but how can I find it?

**→ The Optical Theorem supports this fact**.

Comment: Sorry, the Optical theorem supports $TT^\dagger = 2i {\rm Im}T$. So please forget the second question...

Comment: You can [edit] your question to make changes.

Comment: I think this could work out two ways but I am not sure which argument is used by PS. They could simply be taking $S = iT$ instead of $S = 1 + i T$ (not very convincing) or I think the remaining two terms when written down will be complex conjugate of one another and we get something like $z + z^* = 2 \ \mathrm{Re}(z)$ and then z could turn out to be purely imaginary.

Comment: @asymptoticallyboundedgluon Thank you. Maybe I have to read Chapter 7 of P&S again because P&S postponed discussion about what kind of diagram we have to consider to calculate S-matrix.